# Converting Polymorphic Wrapper of type T to type U?

Tags: c++, templates, types, c++11, polymorphism

Consider the intention behind the following illegal C++11 code:

```
struct Base
{
    template<typename U>
    virtual U convert() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct Derived : Base
{
    T t;

    template<typename U>
    virtual U convert() { return U(t); }
};

struct Any
{
    Base* b;

    template<typename U>
    operator U() { return b->convert<U>(); }
};

int main()
{
    Any a = ...;
    string s = a; // s = a->b->t if T is convertible to string
                  //    fails otherwise with compile error or runtime exception
                  //                            (either acceptable)
}
```

Is there a way to achieve the same or similiar effect with legal code?

(fyi the above way is illegal because `templates may not be ‘virtual’`)

**Update:**

```
struct Base
{
    void* p;
    type_info type;
};

template<typename T>
struct Derived : Base
{
    Derived()
    {
         p = &t; // immovable
         type = typeid(T);
    }

    T t;
};

struct Any
{
    Base* b;

    template<typename T = U, typename U>
    operator U()
    {
        if (b->type != typeid(T))
           throw exception();

        T* t = (T*) b->p;

        return U(*t);
    }
};
```

Comment: Just for those of us who find the concept interesting but don't know C++03/C++11 nearly well enough, could you post the compiler error?

Comment: First of all, a function template cannot be `virtual` (in C++03 and C++11 both). Now, if it cannot be virtual then how can you propagate `U` from `Any` conversion function to the Base's `convert` function which seems to be `virtual` in any case.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure: The illegal part is that `templates may not be ‘virtual’`

Comment: @Nawaz: As I said the code presented is illegal.  It is purely an illustration of the intention.  The question is how to achieve the intention with legal code.

Comment: You can't just do that, you cannot _break the virtual wall_. Closest you could get is by explicitly specifying a few conversions

Comment: @K-ballo: Maybe there is a way that the necessary conversions can be automatically generated by template instantiations.

Comment: No, there isn't, because at no point you have the type of both _source_ and _target_... Unless you specify those conversions explicitly

Comment: @K-ballo: What if a registry of all possible types of T and U were declared somewhere (and any T or U used not on that list would cause a compiler error).  Say for example they were specified as a set of variadic types to some singleton `AnyRegistry<string, int, char, Foo, etc>`.   Given that list of types could the required machinery be automatically generated for any proposed conversion.

Comment: That would be explicitly specifying the types you want it to work for, and yes that would be possible

Comment: @K-ballo: I wonder how `boost::any` and `boost::any_cast` work

Comment: @K-ballo: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/boost/any.hpp

Comment: `boost::any_cast` is pretty simple. Note that it deals with only one type, and it has that type as a template parameter. You don't have the source type as a template parameter at the conversion operator.

Comment: @K-ballo: Yes the relevant part is here: `template<typename ValueType> ValueType * any_cast(any * operand) { return operand &&  operand->type() == typeid(ValueType) ? &static_cast<any::holder<ValueType> *>(operand->content)->held : 0; }`.  Basically they check the `typeid` and then perform a static cast.  In cases where U and T were identical this would work through deduction, in other cases the client could explicitly specify T to get the conversion to a different U.

Comment: No, he couldn't. He would have to specify both **T** and **U**.

Comment: @K-ballo: No, U can always be deduced from the parameter.  T can default to U, or can be explicitly specified.  Ill show you in an update.

Comment: Have you tried it? If you want to specify `T` you need to do `string s = a.operator string< T >();`

Comment: @K-ballo: Easily fixed isn't it?

Comment: Your update is more or less the same as `boost::any`. You have to know the stored type to fetch the value, which was not the case in the original question. Then you just cast it to whatever type you want.

Comment: @n.m.: Mostly correct.  In the case `T=U` the type can be deduced, which is a feature `boost::any` doesn't have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
struct Base
{
  virtual void* convert(const std::type_info&) = 0;
};

template<typename T>
struct Derived : Base
{
  virtual void* convert(const std::type_info& ti)
  { return typeid(T) == ti ? &t : nullptr; }

  T t;
};

struct Any
{
  Base* b;

  template<typename U>
    operator U()
    {
      if (auto p = b->convert(typeid(U)))
        return *static_cast<U*>(p);
      throw std::exception();
    }
};
```

As the other answer says, it's hard to know exactly what you want as you've only shown invalid code, not explained what you're trying to achieve.

**Edit** oh I see now you want it to work for any convertible type, not just exact matches ... then no, you can't turn a `type_info` back into the type it represents, which would be needed for the derived type to test if the given `type_info` corresponded to a type that its stored type is convertible to.  You need to know the correct type and specify it *somehow*, either explicitly or implicitly via deduction. If you then want to convert it to another type, you can do that separately:

```
Any a{ new Derived<int>() };
try {
  char c = a;  // throws
}
catch (...)
{
}
int i = a;        // OK
char c = (int)a;  // OK
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on your update I think that this is what you are trying to do.

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <exception>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
struct Any{
        T* t;
        Any():t(NULL){}
        Any(const T& _t){
                t=new T(_t);
        }
        template<typename U>
        operator U(){
                if(typeid(T)!=typeid(U) || t==NULL)
                        throw std::exception();
                return *t;
        }
};

int main (){
        Any<std::string> a(std::string("Nothing"));
        std::string b=a;
        return 0;
};
```

If this doesn't help please explain in text not code what you are trying to achieve. It'll be useful to tell us also why you want to use those two extra classes Base and Derived.

Comment: See `boost::any`: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/boost/any.hpp.  `Base` is equivilent to `placeholder` and `Derived` is equivilent to `holder`.